# Is there a free visual resource editor for .rc files to translate my software?

Tags: visual-studio, localization, resources, resource-editor

Let me explain. I wanted to allow users of my software to be able to translate it onto foreign languages. My idea was to provide them with a copy of a `.rc` file (plus `resource.h` and some additional .h files with definitions) and have them download a free version of Visual Studio Express and then be able to view and translate all the dialogs, strings, etc.

But ... as I just tried it out, Visual Studio Express does not come with a resource editor... Ha-ha-ha... What a piece of garbage! Did they see that the Xcode that they copied it from does support it....

Anyway, sorry... as you can tell, I'm very disappointed that after having done a lot of work prepping the `.rc` file I learned that everything that my translators can do is open it as text in a "marvelous" Visual Studio Express!

So my question is, is there some software that a translator (who is not a developer!) can use to open a `.rc` file to do visual resource editing (i.e. translation)?

PS. I'm obviously looking for a free solution.
PS2. I created this `.rc` file in my full (paid) version of the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this recently, which integrates into VS (but can be run standalone):

https://github.com/ekkis/Powershell/blob/master/MT.ps1

largely because I was unsatisfied with the solutions out there.  you'll need to get a client id from M$ (but they give you 2M words/month translation free - not bad)